# CSS3 @media calls not working

Tags: html, css

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Cambria, Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", Georgia, serif;
  src: url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
  src: url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #0055cc;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  text-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
}

p {text-align:justify;}
a {text-decoration: none;}

body {
  font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #8080ff url("../imgs/body.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:justify;
}

.shadow {box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;}
.border {
  -moz-border-radius:20px;
  -webkit-border-radius:20px;
  border-radius:20px; 
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #8080FF;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.sidenav {
  height:100%;
  top: 50px;
  width: 16.66%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000099;
  position:sticky!important;
  z-index:999;
  overflow:auto
}

.cont2 {
  height:100%;
  top: 50px;
  width: 83.33%;
  background: #fff url("../imgs/bg-white.png") no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position:sticky!important; 
  z-index:100;
  overflow:auto
}

#logo {width: 100%;}

#logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
}

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {width: 100%;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* For tablets: */
  .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stickyfill/1.1.4/stickyfill.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Gulf Coast Broadband - Wireless Internet for South Louisiana</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Gulf Coast Broadband">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Louisiana,Wireless,Internet,Gulf,Coast,Broadband">
  <meta name="author" content="Christopher Waguespack">
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/content.css">

  <script>
    $(function(){
      $('.navbar').Stickyfill();
      $('.sidenav').Stickyfill();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="logo">
      <img src="imgs/gcb-new.png">
  </div>

  <div class="navbar">
      <h2>&#9784;</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="sidenav col-3">
      <ul>
          <li>&#9736;</li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cont2 col-9">
      <center><h2>Welcome to Gulf Coast Broadband!</h2></center>
      <p>Since 2007, Gulf Coast Broadband has been proudly providing quality wireless internet service to the Bayou Region. From Four-Mile Bayou to the port of West St. Mary, we have offered service to areas that would otherwise be unable to connect to the internet at an affordable price, or at all.</p>
      <p>These days, internet access has become an important part of most people's daily lives. Whether conducting business via email or video, or just simply enjoying quality family time watching movies with the family on Netflix, almost everyone needs access.  Even more notable, applications such as Netflix (media streaming), video chat, and a growing number of online video game require High-Speed Internet access - slower DSL and costly cable just won't do!</p>
      <p>Wireless technology allows us so many options for staying connected to others, whether they are friends and family or business associates. However, to be able to use these incredible communication tools YOU HAVE TO BE CONNECTED to the outside world.</p>
      <p>High Speed Broadband Internet is a Must!</p>
      <p>You can Facebook from your iPad, watch movies from Netflix, read a book on your Kindle, order products from your vendors. The World Wide Web is a virtual encyclopedia of solutions for almost all of your wants, needs or desires.</p>
      <p>Gulf Coast Broadband also provides wireless internet telephone services (Voice over IP - VoIP). This allows for far cheaper service rates with the quality of digital telephone services just like cell phones use today.</p>
      <p>Since 2007, Gulf Coast Broadband has been proudly providing quality wireless internet service to the Bayou Region. From Four-Mile Bayou to the Port of West St. Mary, we have offered service to areas that would otherwise be unable to connect to the internet at an affordable price, or at all.</p>
      <p>These days, internet access has become an important part of most people's daily lives. Whether conducting business via email or video, or just simply enjoying quality family time watching movies with the family on Netflix, almost everyone needs access.  Even more notable, applications such as Netflix (media streaming), video chat, and a growing number of online video game require High-Speed Internet access - slower DSL and costly cable just won't do!</p>
      <p>Wireless technology allows us so many options for staying connected to others, whether they are friends and family or business associates. However, to be able to use these incredible communication tools YOU HAVE TO BE CONNECTED to the outside world.</p>
      <p>High Speed Broadband Internet is a Must!</p>
      <p>You can Facebook from your iPad, watch movies from Netflix, read a book on your Kindle, order products from your vendors. The World Wide Web is a virtual encyclopedia of solutions for almost all of your wants, needs or desires.</p>
      <p>Gulf Coast Broadband also provides wireless internet telephone services (Voice over IP - VoIP). This allows for far cheaper service rates with the quality of digital telephone services just like cell phones use today.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've seen countless people with the same question, and working through many of the possible solutions I cannot figure out what's going on.

I've spent more than a few hours trying so many variations, and every single thing break what little code I have working.

Adding the classes for the media queries to the elements I need to affect also breaks my Sticky navs. Can someone find whatever it is that's not right?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. While some of the code
I used came directly from w3schools, it's
apparently not too friendly with the JS
and floats I'm using on the divs.

Removing:

```
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

and this:

```
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Once those two snips were gone, the @media
queries started responding, and the JS
Sticky divs were no longer broken. If anyone
has any idea why those two class calls would
break things, i'd certainly love to be
enlightened!  :)